# Shell expression that was asked in my test

Tags: bash, shell

I got this in my test recently and i was stumped. The question was to explain what the following shell expression does:

```sh
bang(){bang|bang&};bang
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [Fork bomb](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)

> In computing, a fork bomb is a denial-of-service attack whereby a process 
>   continually replicates itself to deplete available system resources.

The canonical example

```sh
:(){ :|: & };:
```